# Angular 5 [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

When I click the button, I'm sending the 'copyRow' element to the 'copyItem' method. I'm equalizer the 'copyItem' element with the 'item' variable in the 'Typescript' file.

This 'item in the html file' variable when I want to show '[object htmldivelement]' I'm getting as output.

create.component.html

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="form-group copy-row" #copyRow>
       <label>Question</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question title">
    </div>
    {{ item }}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="copyItem(copyRow)">Add</button>
```

create.component.ts

```
  item;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  copyItem(row) {
    this.item = row;
  }
```

> EDIT

My aim is to do a survey project.
When I click on the 'Add' button, the same '#copyRow' element will show in the {{ item }} section. However, I get an output like the second link.

1: http://prntscr.com/j1ncp1
2: http://prntscr.com/j1nd19

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: '[object htmldivelement]' I want the pure html output to appear instead of this output.

Comment: `this.item = row.innerHTML;`

Comment: My aim is to do a survey project. When I click on the 'Add' button, the same '#copyRow' element will show in the {{ item }} section. However, I get an output like the second link.

1: http://prntscr.com/j1ncp1 2: http://prntscr.com/j1nd19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this but this is the explanation of what is happening in your code.

`#copyRow` is a reference to the HTML element & in this case it is a div element. So when you're passing the reference using `copyItem` function, you are actually passing an HTML element.

Putting these things together, the `copyItem` method gets following signature -

```
public item: HTMLElement;

public copyItem(row: HTMLElement): void {
    this.item = row;
    //this is how you get inner HTML
    console.log(row.innerHTML);
    //this is to get inner text
    console.log(row.innerText);
}
```

This is the reason why you are getting `[object HTMLDivElement]` in the template for `item` binding (you are trying to display an object).

You can simply use `{{item.innerHTML}}` or `{{item.innerText}}` to display the inner content of selected HTML element.

Let me know if I'm missing anything.

> EDIT - Alternative Way (Binding in Template)

If you are not doing additional stuff in the component, the binding can be as simple as assigning the HTML element reference directly to the `item` property in template itself -

```
<div class="questions">
    <div class="form-group copy-row" #copyRow>
    <label>Question</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question title">
    </div>
    {{ item?.innerHtml }}
    {{ item?.innerText }}
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="item = copyRow">Add</button>
```

> EDIT 2 (as per discussion in comments)

Try this template to iterate over same HTML on button click -

```
<div class="questions">
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="form-group copy-row">
        <label>Question</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Question title" />
    </div>
</ng-container>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="items = items || []; items.push(1);">Add</button>
```

Just initialise your `items` array as -

```
public items: Array<number> = [1];
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried the alternative way.
But it output in plain text: http://prntscr.com/j1nfkz

Comment: Do you want to display the same HTML below original HTML on button click?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I want to show the "#copyRow" element the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Use ViewChild and ElementRef

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'



@ViewChild('item')
 item: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  copyItem() {
    // this.item -> now you have the reference of the element
  }
```

Comment: I've tried. But instead of printing the form above, it outputs [object HTMLDivElement]: http://prntscr.com/j1ngkd